# Arrow operator to static, non-member function

Tags: c, postgresql, pointers

This piece of Code is used to iterate through a node-structure, but what does the arrow-operator do here, and why does it return the next element?

```c
static inline TupleTableSlot *
ExecProcNode(PlanState *node)
{
    if (node->chgParam != NULL) /* something changed? */
        ExecReScan(node);       /* let ReScan handle this */

    return node->ExecProcNode(node);
}
```

Here the PLanState struct:

```c
typedef struct PlanState
{
    NodeTag     type;

    Plan       *plan;           /* associated Plan node */

    EState     *state;          /* at execution time, states of individual
                                 * nodes point to one EState for the whole
                                 * top-level plan */

    ExecProcNodeMtd ExecProcNode;   /* function to return next tuple */
    ExecProcNodeMtd ExecProcNodeReal;   /* actual function, if above is a
                                         * wrapper */

    Instrumentation *instrument;    /* Optional runtime stats for this node */
    WorkerInstrumentation *worker_instrument;   /* per-worker instrumentation */

    /* Per-worker JIT instrumentation */
    struct SharedJitInstrumentation *worker_jit_instrument;

    /*
     * Common structural data for all Plan types.  These links to subsidiary
     * state trees parallel links in the associated plan tree (except for the
     * subPlan list, which does not exist in the plan tree).
     */
    ExprState  *qual;           /* boolean qual condition */
    struct PlanState *lefttree; /* input plan tree(s) */
    struct PlanState *righttree;

    List       *initPlan;       /* Init SubPlanState nodes (un-correlated expr
                                 * subselects) */
    List       *subPlan;        /* SubPlanState nodes in my expressions */

    /*
     * State for management of parameter-change-driven rescanning
     */
    Bitmapset  *chgParam;       /* set of IDs of changed Params */

    /*
     * Other run-time state needed by most if not all node types.
     */
    TupleTableSlot *ps_ResultTupleSlot; /* slot for my result tuples */
    ExprContext *ps_ExprContext;    /* node's expression-evaluation context */
    ProjectionInfo *ps_ProjInfo;    /* info for doing tuple projection */

    /*
     * Scanslot's descriptor if known. This is a bit of a hack, but otherwise
     * it's hard for expression compilation to optimize based on the
     * descriptor, without encoding knowledge about all executor nodes.
     */
    TupleDesc   scandesc;
} PlanState;
```

Here the struct for the node-object. I dont think it helps, but if you see something i dont, please elaborate.

I dont understand how this piece of code "increments"/iterates through the linked list, especially by using the c-arrow operator

Comment: Clearly it is part of a linked list, where each node contains information relevant to a record, The _arrow_ notation is because the object being incremented is a pointer.   If you can show the rest of the relevant code, in particular the struct in which `node` is defined, answering your questions would be a little more straight forward.  A [mcve] would be useful here.

Comment: Added the PLanState struct, there is no member node tho ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL executor produces result tuples (stored in a `TupleTableSlot`) "on demand". If you need the next result row from an execution plan node, you call its `ExecProcNode` function, which will return the desired result. This will in turn call `ExecProcNode` on other, lower plan nodes as needed.

The struct member `ExecProcNode` is of type `ExecProcNodeMtd`, which is defined as

```c
typedef TupleTableSlot *(*ExecProcNodeMtd) (struct PlanState *pstate);
```

So this is a pointer to the function. When a node is created, the actual executor function for that node type is stored in `ExecProcNode`, and the code could be read as "call whatever executor function is defined for this node".

For example, `ExecInitSeqScan` initializes the scan state like this:

```c
scanstate = makeNode(SeqScanState);
scanstate->ss.ps.plan = (Plan *) node;
scanstate->ss.ps.state = estate;
scanstate->ss.ps.ExecProcNode = ExecSeqScan;
```

So in the case of a sequential scan, the actual function called is `ExecSeqScan`.

If you want, this coding technique implements abstraction in an object-oriented fashion in C.